# Authenticated Employee is Null on HomeFragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make it to where my Employee model populates labels and images on the HomeFragment whenever they login or register on the app. However, when I try to, the HomeFragment logs that the `currentEmployee` is Null. The weird thing is that I have it to where if authentication is null, they are presented with the WelcomeActivity, and if it's authenticates, the MainActivity/HomeFragment is presented as I'm on a BottomNavigationView once they log in. My question to you is, is my `MyUtil` functions in the wrong spot, or should I be setting the `currentEmployee` somewhere in my onCreateView? Thank you!

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        var currentEmployee: Employee? = null
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        MyUtil.fetchCurrentEmployee()
        MyUtil.fetchCurrentEmployeeLocation()

        val profileImage = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.menuProfileImageView)
        Picasso.get().load(currentEmployee?.profileImageUrl).into(profileImage)
        profileImage.setOnClickListener {
            activity.let {
                val menuIntent = Intent(it, MenuActivity::class.java)
                it?.startActivity(menuIntent)
            }
        }

        val homeProfileImage = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.homeProfileImageView)
        val fullname = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fullnameTextView)
        val companyName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.companyNameTextView)
        val businessCategory = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.businessCategoryTextView)
        val phoneNumber = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.phoneNumberTextView)
        val email = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.emailTextView)

        Picasso.get().load(currentEmployee?.profileImageUrl).into(homeProfileImage)
        fullname.text = currentEmployee?.fullname
        companyName.text = currentEmployee?.companyName
        businessCategory.text =  currentEmployee?.businessCategory
        phoneNumber.text = currentEmployee?.phoneNumber
        email.text = currentEmployee?.email

        return view
    }

}
```

**MyUtil.kt**

```
class MyUtil {
    companion object {
        var currentEmployee: Employee? = null

        fun fetchCurrentEmployee() {

            val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
            val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("/$REF_EMPLOYEES/$uid")

            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    currentEmployee = Employee(
                        snapshot.child("uid").getValue(String::class.java)!! ,
                        snapshot.child("fullname").getValue(String::class.java)!! ,
                        snapshot.child("companyName").getValue(String::class.java)!! ,
                        snapshot.child("businessCategory").getValue(String::class.java)!! ,
                        snapshot.child("email").getValue(String::class.java)!! ,
                        snapshot.child("phoneNumber").getValue(String::class.java)!! ,
                        snapshot.child("username").getValue(String::class.java)!! ,
                        snapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue(String::class.java)!!
                    )
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }
            })

        }

}
```

**WelcomeActivity.kt**

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        auth.addAuthStateListener {
            if (it.currentUser != null) {
                val mainIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(mainIntent)
            } else {
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider [using an auth state listener](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android), rather than (synchronously) checking the `currentUser` property.

Comment: K, added the authState listener, but still running into the issue.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you did with the auth state listener please, as just adding a listener won't change any of the existing behavior.

Comment: Edited my code for you @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: When the auth state listener gets called, is its` it.currentUser` `null` or does it have a value? And if it's `null`, what makes you think that it should have any value? (i.e. are you sure you're signing a user in, given that the code you shared doesn't call any of the `signIn` APIs of Firebase Authentication as far as I can see at a glance.

Comment: Yes honestly I figured out the issue. Registration and logging in weren’t the problem. My `MyUtil.fetchCurrentEmployee()` was loading data slowly so I took the code and put it in HomeFragment.